# How to find the row with maximum number of 1s in a matrix

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a matrix with boolean values:

```
require 'matrix'
m1 = Matrix[[0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]
```

I want to find the row with the maximum number of `1`s. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does it contain only 1 & 0 ?

Comment: What's the expected result for the given matrix? `[1,1,1,1]`, `Vector[1,1,1,1]`, `2` (the row's zero-based index) or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimized solution: - Start checking from top right corner and traverse to the left of matrix till you are getting `1`. When 0 is encountered, traverse down the matrix and repeat.

```
row = nil
j = m1.row_count - 1
(0...m1.row_count).each.with_index do |i|
  while m1[i,j] == 1 do
    row = i
    j -= 1
  end
end
puts row
```

Assumptions:
1. Rows are sorted.
2. It's nxn matrix.

For more, refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-row-number-binary-matrix-maximum-number-1s/)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach probably is

```
m1.row_vectors.max_by { |e| e.count(1) }
#=> Vector[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: yes , i need to create a array boolean 2d array where each row is sorted and then find the max 1s

Comment: Do you need to find the row index or what?

Comment: I can't test right now but you might be able to use `...max_by(&:sum)` too.

Comment: @SagarPandya It is valid only for a binary matrix. Unfortunately, the question does not have info about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
m1.row_vectors.max_by(&:sum)
  #=> Vector[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

or

```
m1.to_a.max_by(&:sum)
  #=> [1,1,1,1]
```

depending on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowWithMax1s(vector<vector<int> > arr, int n, int m) {
int maxOneIndex = -1;
int currCol = m-1;
    
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
while(currCol >=0 && arr[i][currCol] == 1){
maxOneIndex = i;
currCol--;
}
}
return maxOneIndex;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?